# Why won't this code run in Pine Script 4? "Undeclared identifier"

Tags: algorithmic-trading, pine-script

Resources are still Pine Script 3 heavy, so I think I'm mixing something up:

I tried to create an Average Daily Range indicator, which is basically the ATR that takes a "D" input no matter what the time frame of the current chart is. My code works perfectly fine on Pine Script 3, but Pine Script 4 throws out the following errors:

```
line 4: Undeclared identifier `resolution`;
line 6: Undeclared identifier `tickerid`;
line 6: Undeclared identifier `dRange`;
line 8: Undeclared identifier `adRange`
```

The docs indicate `resolution` is still an `input()` argument, and I'm not sure why anything else is called "undeclared".

My full code is:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Average Daily Range", shorttitle="ADR", overlay=false)

dRange = input(defval="D", title="Daily Range", type=resolution)

adRange = security(tickerid, dRange, rma(tr, 5))

plot(adRange, title = "ADR", color=#000000, transp=0)
```

What are these "Undeclared identifiers"? And what must I do differently in Pine Script 4 so that I'm getting the same result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v4 RefMan is here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/

v4 UserMan is here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html

Since compiler is returning an error on line 4 which uses `input()`, makes sense to look up the function in refman, where you will find that the proper argument to `type=` parameter for what you want is now `input.resolution`. Being unable to initialize variable `dRange` because of the error, the compiler also gives an error on that variable. Same goes with `adRange`, which you've fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it, but still don't know what "undeclared identifiers" were. I assume it's just Pine's way of saying that `dRange` violated the new rules with its variable `resolution`, and that `adRange` was creating problems with the un-used `tickerid`, which has been replaced by `syminfo.tickerid` in PineScript 4.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Average Daily Range", shorttitle="ADR", overlay=false)

adRange = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", rma(tr, 5))

plot(adRange, title="ADR", color=#000000, transp=0)
```

Comment: An identifier is any text that names a "thing" (variable, function, whatever). So, for example: `study` is an identifier, `adRange` is an identifier, `security` is an identifier, `rma` is an identifier and so on. "Undeclared identifier" means that you tried to use an identifier that wasn't declared: that is, an identifier that it doesn't know about. In pine, when you declare a variable like your `adRange = ...` that also declares the identifier. If you tried to use `adRange` before that line, you would get the undeclared error, but after that line you do not. Basically, pine must know about...

Comment: ...an identifier before you can use it. If you tried to use it before its declared, pine doesn't know what it is, so it complains. In your code, `resolution` was used but it's not a built in variable and not a variable you defined, so you got the error.
Ok, with that explanation out of the way, the reason `resolution` gave you an error is that it was built in for pine v3, but pine v4 moved a bunch of things to avoid name clashes. You need to use `input.resolution` instead now.